# Signalr client as a windows service running on .net framework 3.5

Tags: c#, windows-services, signalr, owin, signalr.client

I have to send messages to my **signalr** hubs from my windows services. Some of my windows services run on .net framework 3.5. My first step was adding this package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nivot.SignalR.Client.Net35/

Here is my whole test code for this scenario:

```
public partial class WinSer35 : ServiceBase
{
    private HubConnection hubConnection;
    private IHubProxy priceProxy;

    public WinSer35()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/signalr", useDefaultUrl: false);
        priceProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("PriceHub");
        hubConnection.Start().Wait();

        TestPrice testPrice = new TestPrice() { Id = 1, Buy = 1.2345, Sell = 9.8765, Symbol = "EURUSD" };
        priceProxy.Invoke("NotifySubscribers", testPrice).Wait();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {

    }
}
```

On line:

> hubConnection.Start().Wait();

I'm getting the following exception:

> Service cannot be started. System.AggregateException: AggregateException_ctor_DefaultMessage ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.HttpHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(IAsyncResult ar)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endMethod, TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
>      at WinSer35.WinSer35.OnStart(String[] args) in c:\Users\anilcaliskan\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication1\WinSer35\WinSer35.cs:line 28
>      at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest....

Same code piece running on .net framework 4.5 and referenced the default Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client dll works as expected.

Do you have any suggestions? Think of I have a few other dependencies and I can not compile my windows services in a version greater than .net framework 3.5.

Comment: If its truly a 3.5 library it should not even have those methods because thats is 4.5 code

Comment: Thanks @Anders. I think you are right. I found a way to upgrade my windows services to .net framework 4.5. I'll accept if you add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its truly a 3.5 library it should not even have those methods because that is 4.5 code